# fetch data from left and right joined tables in mysql which contains three tables

Tags: mysql

I had three tables from which i am want fetch data.

1. table one with name cp_sampleSheet consists of columns like run,lane,sample_id,project.
2. second table with name cp_samp_R1 consists of columns like sample_id,raw_bases,raw_reads.
3. third table with name cp_samp_R2 consists of columns like sample_id,raw_bases2,raw_reads2.

I can fetch tha data from three tables if sample_id is present in three tables, but i want to fetch the data if sample_id is not present in third table also.

```
 SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2
 FROM cp_sampleSheet a
 LEFT JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id
 LEFT JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id
 where (b.raw_bases + c.raw_bases2) ='$value'";
```

Comment: i am unable to get data when there is no sample in third table,plz help me to trouble shoot this.

Comment: you can use not in query

Comment: most of the samples are present in three tables. only few samples contains two tables

Comment: i want to fetch from three tables based on addition of raw_bases in second table and raw_bases2 in third table, where sample_id in first table is taken as a connection to remaining tables

Comment: Your where criteria is at odds with what you are saying because it requires a value to be present in the 3rd table.

Comment: any other sql query  for that

Comment: how to get data from all tables irrespective of third table